# Cambiar fecha dependiendo de Select

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un form con algunos cambios
-Fecha Inicial
-Fecha Final
-Mercado
-Origen

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
   <label for="selectmercado"><?php echo $palabras['controles']['mercado'];?></label>
        <select id="selectmercado" name="selectmercado" class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option value="mda">MDA</option>
            <option value="mtr">MTR</option>                            
        </select>
</div>    
<div class="col-sm-3">
     <label for="minDate"><?php echo $palabras['controles']['fecha_ini'];?></label>
     <input id="minDate" name="minDate" class="form-control" type="date" min="<?php echo $fecha_minima; ?>" max="<?php echo $fecha_actual; ?>" value="<?php echo $fecha_fin_select;?>" />
     <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2 pb-0 mb-0" role="alert" id="minDateError" style="display: none">
          <span><p>Favor de introducir una fecha.</p></span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
     <label for="maxDate"><?php echo $palabras['controles']['fecha_final'];?></label>
     <input id="maxDate" name="maxDate" class="form-control" type="date" min="<?php echo $fecha_minima; ?>" max="<?php echo $fecha_actual; ?>" value="<?php echo $fecha_actual;?>" />
     <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2 pb-0 mb-0" role="alert" id="maxDateError" style="display: none">
          <span><p>Favor de introducir una fecha.</p></span>
     </div>
</div>                                                      
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="selectmercado"><?php echo $palabras['controles']['mercado'];?></label>
    <select id="selectmercado" name="selectmercado" class="form-control selectpicker">
          <option value="mda">MDA</option>
          <option value="mtr">MTR</option>                            
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="nd_dropdown"><?php echo $palabras['controles']['origen'];?></label>
    <select id="nd_dropdown" name="nd_dropdown" class="form-control selectpicker live_search">
    <?php                                                                   
    $sql = "SELECT origen FROM listado ORDER BY CAST(origen as UNSIGNED)";
    $query = $mysqli -> query ($sql);
    while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       echo "<option value='".$valores['origen']."'>".$valores['origen']."</option>";}
    ?>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer, cuando selecciona mercado (MDA o MTR) la fecha final cambie
Ejemplo seleccionamos MDA la fecha final seria el dia de hoy
Pero si seleccionamos MTR la fecha final seria el dia de hoy menos 5 dias.

Alguien me podrian orientar?
Lo que he intentado es esto en javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name=mercado]").change(function(){
            alert($('select[name=mercado]').val());
            $('input[name=mercado]').val($(this).val());
        });
```

pude obtener el valor del select pero como le resto los 5 dias y se lo agrego al campo fecha como fecha maxima?

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución a la cual llegué.

Realicé un script:

```
<script>
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm;
}
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

var fecha = new Date($('#fech').val());
var dias = 6; // Número de días a agregar
fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() - dias);
var dd_mtr = fecha.getDate();
var mm_mtr = fecha.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy_mtr = fecha.getFullYear();
fecha = yyyy_mtr + '-' + mm_mtr + '-' + dd_mtr;


$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select[name=selectmercado]").change(function() {

    switch (document.getElementById("selectmercado").value) {
      case "mda":
        $("#maxDate").val(today);
        break;
      case "mtr":
        $("#maxDate").val("2022-01-06");
        $("maxDate").attr({
          "max": "2022-01-06", // substitute your own
          "min": "2021-01-01" // values (or variables) here
        });
        $("input").attr({
          "max": "2022-01-06", // substitute your own
          "min": "2021-01-01" // values (or variables) here
        });
        break;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Espero le funcione a alguien más.

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas logrado. Cuando respondas preguntas procura incorporar algo de explicación adicional que ayude a entender la respuesta a la pregunta concreta. Poniendo solo el código no es suficiente para una respuesta de calidad, a menos que esté comentado, o como decia, agregando una breve pero concisa explicación al final en modo texto de los puntos claves para resolver la pregunta.